# Failed to Connect: Unknown Protocol After Adding Mail Account

Tags: civimail, error, google, oauth

Civicrm 5.44.0, Wordpress 5.8.2, Google's Gmail APIs

Steps:

1. Administer > CiviMail >  Mail Accounts
2. Add Google Mail

I am encountering the following error when clicking Save & Test:
[image: Failed to Connect Error]

It said to look at the log for more details, and this is what the log rendered:

```
Dec 15 15:31:38  [warning] MailSettings: Failed to establish test connection
    Array
    (
        [exception] => Exception: "Unknown protocol "
    #0 /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Action/MailSettings/TestConnection.php(28): CRM_Mailing_MailStore::getStore()
    #1 /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Generic/BasicBatchAction.php(72): Civi\Api4\Action\MailSettings\TestConnection->doTask()
    #2 /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Provider/ActionObjectProvider.php(68): Civi\Api4\Generic\BasicBatchAction->_run()
    #3 /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(149): Civi\Api4\Provider\ActionObjectProvider->invoke()
    #4 /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Generic/AbstractAction.php(234): Civi\API\Kernel->runRequest()
    #5 /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/api.php(85): Civi\Api4\Generic\AbstractAction->execute()
    #6 /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Form/MailSettings.php(214): civicrm_api4()
    #7 /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(534): CRM_Admin_Form_MailSettings->postProcess()
    #8 /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Upload.php(152): CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()
    #9 /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Upload.php(119): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Upload->realPerform()
    #10 /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Upload->perform()
    #11 /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle()
    #12 /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(352): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle()
    #13 /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php(395): CRM_Core_Controller->run()
    #14 /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php(140): CRM_Core_Page_Basic->edit()
    #15 /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(313): CRM_Core_Page_Basic->run()
    #16 /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(69): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem()
    #17 /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(36): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke()
    #18 /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1169): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke()
    #19 /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(303): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke()
    #20 /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(327): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
    #21 /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-includes/plugin.php(470): WP_Hook->do_action()
    #22 /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php(259): do_action()
    #23 {main}
    
    )
```

The settings I am trying to use are the standard ones generated by the Add a Google Mail, and are enumerated as follows:

```
Server: imap.gmail.com
Username: <myemail@domain.com>
Password: *blank*
Localpart: *blank*
Email Domain: <domain.com>
Return-Path: *blank*
Protocol: IMAP
Source: *blank*
Use SSL: ✅
Used For: Email-to-activity Processing
```

In my Oauth, I can see valid tokens were generated for my account. Google didn't provide any specific error during the process.

Comment: For the time being, I just generated an App Password and manually entered in a Mail Account as if Oauth never existed. This has perhaps been the most reliable connection so far.